# FindBy return the same object

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm programming a notifications system. Each  notification has an id sender, id receiver and can have the id of an event (foreign key, can be null). I'm trying to get all the notifications where the column us_id_receiver = X.

In my database, user with id X has two records as receiver. I should get these two records but doctrine returns me two similar records...

My query is:
"$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('HeaventUserBundle:Notification')->findBy(array('usIdReceiver' => $id));"

```
Array
(
[0] => Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification Object
    (
        [usIdSender:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => 10
        [usIdReceiver:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => 1
        [nfRead:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => 
        [nfMessage:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => started to follow you
        [nfDate:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-09-04 22:42:50.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

        [evId:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => 
    )

[1] => Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification Object
    (
        [usIdSender:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => 10
        [usIdReceiver:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => 1
        [nfRead:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => 
        [nfMessage:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => started to follow you
        [nfDate:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-09-04 22:42:50.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

        [evId:Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\Notification:private] => 
    )

)
```

But in my database these two records are not similar, the only real difference is that one has an event id and the other one not.

here is the entities.

```
<?php

namespace Heavent\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Notification
*
* @ORM\Table(name="c_notification")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\NotificationRepository")
*/
class Notification
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="us_id_sender", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $usIdSender;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="us_id_receiver", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $usIdReceiver;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nf_date", type="datetime")
 */
private $nfDate;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ev_id", referencedColumnName="ev_id")
 *
 */
private $evId;


/**
 * Get usIdSender
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getUsIdSender()
{
    return $this->usIdSender;
}

/**
 * Set usIdSender
 *
 * @return Notification
 */
public function setUsIdSender($id)
{
    $this->usIdSender = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set usIdReceiver
 *
 * @param integer $usIdReceiver
 * @return Notification
 */
public function setUsIdReceiver($usIdReceiver)
{
    $this->usIdReceiver = $usIdReceiver;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get usIdReceiver
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getUsIdReceiver()
{
    return $this->usIdReceiver;
}

/**
 * Set nfDate
 *
 * @param string $nfDate
 * @return Notification
 */
public function setNfDate($nfDate)
{
    $this->nfDate = $nfDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nfDate
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNfDate()
{
    return $this->nfDate;
}

/**
 * Set evId
 *
 * @param integer $evId
 * @return Notification
 */
public function setEvId($evId)
{
    $this->eEventEvId = $evId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get evId
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getEvId()
{
    return $this->evId;
}
}
```

```
namespace Heavent\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Event
*
* @ORM\Table(name="e_event")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Heavent\UserBundle\Entity\EventRepository")
*/
class Event
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ev_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="ev_name", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $evName;

...
}
```

I think that my relation between these two entities is the problem. But I cannot find the issue by myself.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you define a an association on a property e.g: `$evId`, then that field won't be the id of the related entity, but the **instance**, so it won't be an `integer` but an `Event` object, when you call `setEvId($evId);` in your code, then `$evId` should be an instance of `Event`.